# Sorting a python dictionary without sorting the inner dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains another dictionary. As shown in the code below, *extract()* returns the inner dictionary. I'm adding the return of *extract()* to another dictionary *new_dict*

```
def extract(data):
 # Some Calculations
     dict = {
        "a" : bias_t,
        "b" : resolution,
        "c" : coeffts,
        "d" : length
        }
     return dict

def fun2():
    # A loop that gets the value of line
    for ids in some_dict.items():                 # Some_dict already is sorted
      new_dict[ids] = extract(line)

    for key in sorted(new_dict):
        data[key] = new_dict[key]            # data is another dictionary which is initialized as empty

    json.dump(data, open(JSON_FILE, 'w'), indent = 4, sort_keys = True, separators  = (",", " : "))
```

I'm facing two issues here:

***1***. When I open the *json* file, the keys are not in sorted form. I have keys from 50 till 400. In the *json* file, I get the keys from 100 till 400 and then 50 till 99.

```
"101" : {

    },
"103" : {

    }
    # So on ...
"403" : {

    },
"405" : {


    },
"59" : {

    }
    # So on till 99
"99" : {

    }
```

***2***. I need the inner dictionary to be in the same way that I'm adding them. In the function *extract* I'm adding the values to the dictionary in the order, a,b,c,d. In the final JSON file, it comes  as sorted.

I tried without *sort_keys* in *json.dump()* and without the final sorting *for* loop. When I try with *sort_keys = False* and with the sorting *for* loop, I'm getting an unsorted *json* file, btt the inner dictionary issues i.e issue ***2*** becomes solved. If I try with the *sort_keys = True*, the issues ***1*** and ***2*** both happens.

Comment: Your `data` variable should be an `OrderedDict` since it ensures you that the order of how the items are added is preserved.

Comment: Did you try using an OrderedDict as @FarhoodET mentioned in your `extract` method? I think that should preserve your inner dict order. Secondly, define your `new_dict` as `OrderedDict` and it should preserve the order of keys too.